# Error with ASP.NET 3.5 application deployment

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this error while deploying a ASP.NET 3.5 applcation on a web server. the target server is `Windows 2008R2` with `.NET framework 4.0` installed. Line 5 is the one that throws an error. I have included all the DLLS that are used in the application.

Please let me know how to fix this issue, without having to upgrade the application to .NET framework 4 appl.

```
4:  <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
5:      <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
6:      <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Comment: is .NET Framework 3.5 installed on the web server?

Comment: Can you throw the error up on here so we can examine? Also the trace stack from the localhost.

Comment: Assuming you have a recent versin of the .NET framework installed on the server, what version of the .NET framework is selected under the ASP.NET tab in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Check, is the .NET Framework **3.5** is installed. I'm sure that it is not.
So install it, as you are referensing the **3.5** types in your `web.config`, and they can reference other libraries which are not presented on your server.
If this is not an option, change the line to reference the **4.0** class.

Also check the runtime version for your application pool for this application in the IIS on your server.